# Filter mvn dependency:tree output to only show unique libraries

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am looking to output mvn dependency:tree to a text file. I would like the text file/output to only include unique libraries (i.e. no duplicates). How can I filter the output accordingly?

Comment: This guide shows you how to do both: https://mincong.io/2019/11/11/inspect-maven-dependency-tree/.

Comment: The documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html has a part: `mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=text`?